# Error en Snack bar: Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Estoy intentando mostrar un Snack bar en un fragment pero me da el siguiente error:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View
>   android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Este error sucede cuando quiero mostrar mi Snack bar mediante un boton, no entiendo por que sucede el error, este es mi codigo del Snack bar:

```
public void desplegar() {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                "Se ha añadido a tus favoritos", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction(getString(R.string.verfav), new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.qwe, new Favoritos());
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        //ACTION
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textoblanco));
        View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
        //BACKGROUND
        snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar));
        //MESSAGE
        TextView mensaje = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        mensaje.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textoblanco));

        snackbar.show();
    }
```

ya intente con diferentes formas pero no me han funcionado, no se porque se muestra ese error, este es mi codigo completo:

```
public class Inicio extends Fragment implements noticiasAdapter.OnEventMovieListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener{

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<Noticias> noticias;
    private noticiasAdapter noticiasadapter;
    public static final String TAG = Noticias.class.getName();

    RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;

    Context context;

    public Inicio(){

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inicio, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        noticias = new ArrayList<>();
        noticiasadapter = new noticiasAdapter(noticias);
        noticiasadapter.setOnEventMovieListener(this);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
        cargarWebService();

        return view;
    }

    private void cargarWebService() {

        String url = "http://192.168.1.72:80/webservicemgrex/listaNoticias.php";
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Noticias news = null;
        JSONArray json = response.optJSONArray("inicio");

        try{
            for (int i=0; i<json.length(); i++){
                news = new Noticias();
                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

                news.setIdNoticia(jsonObject.optInt("idNoticia"));
                news.setTituloNoticia(jsonObject.optString("tituloNoticia"));
                news.setSubtituloNoticia(jsonObject.getString("subtituloNoticia"));
                news.setImagenNoticia(jsonObject.getString("imagenNoticia"));
                news.setDescripcionNoticia(jsonObject.getString("descripcionNoticia"));
                noticias.add(news);
            }

            noticiasAdapter adapter = new noticiasAdapter(noticias);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            noticiasadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }catch (JSONException e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error al cargar la informacion del servidor: "+e, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"No se pudo consultar los registros: "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("Error","No se pudo consultar el registro: "+error.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    //Revisar este bloque

    @Override
    public void vistaDetalle(String tituloNoticia, String subtituloNoticia, String imagenNoticia, String descripcionNoticia) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DescripcionNoticias.class);
        intent.putExtra("titulon",tituloNoticia);
        intent.putExtra("descripcionn", descripcionNoticia);
        intent.putExtra("imagen", imagenNoticia);
        startActivity(intent);
        getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.left_out);
        }


    public void desplegar() {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                "Se ha añadido a tus favoritos", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction(getString(R.string.verfav), new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.qwe, new Favoritos());
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        //ACTION
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textoblanco));
        View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
        //BACKGROUND
        snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar));
        //MESSAGE
        TextView mensaje = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        mensaje.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textoblanco));

        snackbar.show();
    }
}
```

Este es el XML que se carga en ese fragmento:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.enriq.seccion15update.Principal"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        tools:context=".Principal">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

y este es mi cardview que cargo para mostrar el contenido:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tituloNoticia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:text="@string/tituloNoticia"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:textSize="18sp" tools:targetApi="jelly_bean"/>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtituloNoticia"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:text="@string/subitutloNoticias"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif" tools:targetApi="jelly_bean"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imagenNotica"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/linea_divisora_de_texto_y_video"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/example" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:tint="@color/barraestatus"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/textoblanco"
        app:elevation="5dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/barraestatus"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/unliked" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/descripcionNoticias"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Descripcion"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.Widget.PopupMenu.Small"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showMore"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Material.Button.Borderless"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:shadowColor="@color/barraestatus"
        android:text="Ver nota completa"
        android:textColor="@color/barraestatus"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:tint="@color/barraestatus"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/textoblanco" tools:targetApi="lollipop"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

El metodo desplegar lo mando a llamar desde esta clase que se llama noticiasWebService, es solamente una clase que cree para poder ejecutar otro webService:

```
public class noticiasWebService extends AppCompatActivity implements Response.Listener<JSONObject>, Response.ErrorListener {

    RequestQueue request;
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    public void update(String tituloNoticia, String subtituloNoticia, String imagenNoticia, String descripcionNoticia, Context context) {

        String url = "http://192.168.1.72:80/webservicemgrex/agregarFavoritos.php?tituloFavorito="+tituloNoticia+"" +
                "&subtituloFavorito="+subtituloNoticia+
                "&imagenFavorito="+imagenNoticia+
                "&descripcionFavoritos="+descripcionNoticia;

        url = url.replace(" ","%20");
        request = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,url,null,this,this);
        request.add(jsonObjectRequest);

        Inicio inicio = new Inicio();
        inicio.desplegar();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
        Log.i("Error","Se haregistrado con exito: "+response);
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.i("Error","No se pudo consultar el registro: "+error.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Revisa tu layout, hay algún elemento al que estás haciendo referencia con `findViewById` que no existe en el layout que estás cargando.

Comment: Hola, si he revisado pero hasta donde se ese no es el problema porque cuando uso esta linea: getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content)  es para obtener la vista donde se pueda mostrar el snack bar pero no me deja

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: no está hallando el elemento cuyo ID estás poniendo. ¿Seguro que el layout tiene ese nombre o ID? Comparte el XML del layout.

Comment: Listo ya agregue a mi pregunta el xml y el xml donde cargo mis cardviews

Comment: @EnriqueEspinosa define de donde llamas el método desplegar() .

Comment: @Jorgesys ya agrege el codigo desde donde mando a llamar a  mi metodo desplegar(), la clase desde donde llamo a ese metodo la uso para ejecutar otro webservice.

Comment: Creo es una buena practica checar si no es null getactivity() antes de usarlo. if(getActivity() != null)

Comment: @EnriqueEspinosa agrego una respuesta donde explico el problema y agrego una opción.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar tu RecyclerView como punto de referencia para el SnackBar. Por ejemplo:

```
  Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(recyclerView, "Se ha añadido a tus favoritos", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Lo que pasa es que buscas una vista que no existe en el layout de tu actividad.

Comment: Hola, de echo si pongo mi recycler view como punto de referencia me da este error: 

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No suitable parent found from the given view. Please provide a valid view.

por eso que usaba esta linea: getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content) para obtener la vista root

Answer (score 0):

Es correcta la forma de cargar el Snackbar, pero el problema aquí es que tratas de llamar el método `desplegar()` que se encuentra en un `Fragment`, esto es incorrecto

```
  Inicio inicio = new Inicio();
  inicio.desplegar();
```

lo que sucede aquí es que este `Fragment` no "ha sido cargado desde una `Activity`" por lo tanto `getActivity()` tendrá un valor `null`.

---

Si deseas llamar el método para crear el `SnackBar` desde la clase `Inicio`, debes crear un método estático que reciba la vista raíz:

```
public static void desplegar(View rootView) {
        Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(rootView,
                "Se ha añadido a tus favoritos", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction(getString(R.string.verfav), new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(R.id.qwe, new Favoritos());
                transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        //ACTION
        snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textoblanco));
        View snackBarView = snackbar.getView();
        //BACKGROUND
        snackBarView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.toolbar));
        //MESSAGE
        TextView mensaje = (TextView) snackBarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
        mensaje.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.textoblanco));

        snackbar.show();
    }
}
```

y llamarías de esta forma el método desde tu `Activity`:

```
Inicio.desplegar(findViewById(android.R.id.content));
```

Con esto se mostraría el `Snackbar` sin problema en tu `Activity`

Comment: Ya probe la solucion y si se corrige el problema del getActivity = null, pero ahora me muestra este error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window$Callback android.view.Window.getCallback()' on a null object reference

Comment: Tambien si defino el metodo como static me muestra un error en el getFragment() y en getString()

Comment: Es únicamente este método el que debe ser marcado como static , ah pero veo que no llamas el método desde onCreate() de la Activity si no desde update()  ?

Comment: Si, lo que pasa es que el metodo update se dispara cuando presiono un boton flotante y este recibe la informacion que quiero guardar en la base de datos por eso el metodo esta como update(String tituloNticia, String subtituloNoticia, etc)